# How to run 32 bit exe on a 64 bit system windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64

Is it possible to run an executable made for 32 bit architecture on a 64 bit system windows 7 (ultimate) ?

It's actually a simulator for a game which runs python script and give output according to my C++ code.

Comment: what's the problem with double clicking the file of typing the filename (with path if needed)?

Comment: It shows error with a dialogue box, that it's not meant for your system. Check whether you have a x64 or x84 system.

Comment: That means you're running 32-bit windows and trying to run 64-bit executable, or even worse, run ARM or some other Windows architectures' executable

Comment: No, I have 64 bit Windows, and I am trying to run game.exe which was meant for 32 bit system. I think I will run it either in Linux (Ubuntu) or use a VM.

Comment: in that case your executable is not even a Windows executable

Comment: If you have software that says it can't run on 64-bit Windows, it's probably a 16-bit application, not a 32-bit one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A 32-bit program is supposed to run on a 64-bit system. That is why Windows has both a *Program Files* and a *Program Files x86* as the x86 folder refers to 32-bit programs.

Answer (score 3):

in general it should work
for more information on this see:
http://celframe.com/supportsuite/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/367/0/how-to-run-32-bit-application-in-64-bit-windows-operating-system

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run an executable made for 32 bit architecture on a 64 bit system windows 7 (ultimate) ?

Yes, using a virtual PC emulator you can achieve this.

Link : [Windows virtual PC wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC)

Download : [XP mod and virtual PC](https://www.askvg.com/direct-download-link-official-links-to-download-windows-xp-mode-and-windows-virtual-pc-for-windows-7/)

Comment: You definately don't need a virtual PC emulator to do this.